# adding ngAnimate to controller makes app to not displaying content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to add animation when changing the content inside a my html using ng-inculde, but when ever i add ['ngAnimate'] in the declaration of the controller all of the content inside the main tag simply dissapear.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div  ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <main ng-init="nav('data/table.html')">
                <div ng-include="filePath">
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ngAnimate']);


myApp.controller ('firstCtrl', function($scope, PersonService){

    $scope.users = PersonService.list();
    $scope.saveUser = function () {
        PersonService.save($scope.newuser);
        $scope.newuser = {};
    }


    $scope.nav = function(path){
        $scope.filePath = path;
    }
})
```

this code wont work since im adding ['ngAnimate'] but if i'll delete it and keep the brackets empty the content will display. can someone tell me why and if its the correct way to get the animation when the content changes (table.html changes to a different file)

this is the header part incase needed:

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about your exact problem but you should start with ordering your scripts. jQuery can be loaded before angular, but any modules should be loaded after. And it should also help if you at least use the same version for angular as for the the rest of your modules. https://code.angularjs.org/.  NgAnimate has gone through some heavy changes so I would assume that would fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Give reference of angular-animate.min.js file in order to use 'ngAnimate' module. You have to give reference of this file after angular.min.js.